# loop form element in javascript

Tags: javascript

Good evening everyone ! I have a problem. In a web page I have to publish a series of form . The number of forms to be displayed is contained in a JavaScript variable. Even the content to show in form is in a Javascript array . In php I can make a loop and insert inside an html form , I know , but in javascript how can I do ? Thanks to all who help me !

Comment: In JS it's exactly the same. You can make a loop and insert inside an html form.

Comment: Take a look at a js template framework.  I personally like http://handlebarsjs.com/ but there are lots of others.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I inserted the html in a document.write. I did so:

```
document.write("<br> <br> test");
```

Thank you all!